# how to implement shorthand validation in angular forms?

Tags: angular-forms

How to use validation in angular forms
i have tried that

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
<label for="exampleInputPassword1">Email</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="toEmail" >
<div *ngIf="form.controls['toEmail'].errors?.required && 
form.controls['toEmail'].errors?.email">
Enter correct email
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div *ngIf="form.controls['controlName'].dirty && form.controls['controlName'].invalid">          
  <p *ngIf="group.controls['controlName'].errors['required']">required message here..</p> 
  <p *ngIf="group.controls['controlName'].errors['email']">Email validation message here..</p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Validation can depend on the type of forms being used, since you attempted to use Reactive forms you can do this (this example validates phone number based on the provided regex).. Good lucky

1. in your .html file do this

   ```
        <form  [formGroup]="myForm"  novalidate>
          <label for="input-char-counter1">Phone ## </label>
          <input  type="text" maxlength="10"formControlName="mob" 
          name="phonenumber" class="form-control">
           <div *ngIf="m['mob'].touched && m['mob'].invalid" class="alert alert- 
               danger">
           </div>
        <div class="error" *ngIf="m['mob'].errors?.['required']">Please enter 
            mobile number
        </div>
        <div class="error" *ngIf="m['mob'].errors?.['pattern']">Phone #
           should have 10 digits and should start with ....
        </div>
         <button   type="button"  [disabled]="!myForm.valid" 
            (click)="sms()">Send Message
         </button>
     </form>
   ```

Then in your example.component.ts

```
public myForm: FormGroup;
```

then inside the constructor you can initialize like so:

```
     this.myForm = formBuilder.group({
      mob: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^07[1378][0-9]{7}$")]],
    })
```

after the constructor put this method

```
  get m(){
return this.myForm.controls;
```

}

Done:: don't forget to import

```
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
```

in your component.ts

Also in the app.module.ts, add `ReactiveFormsModule` in your imports